# umlauts from ios to php

Tags: php, ios, objective-c

i'm sending text from ios to php and save it in a sql database.
but umlauts like "äöü" are saving as \344 etc.

i dont know what i can do ...

that are my steps:

in xcode:

```
        NSData *data = [[_textInput getText] dataUsingEncoding:NSNonLossyASCIIStringEncoding];
        NSString *goodValue = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:data encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];

        NSString *post = [[NSString alloc] initWithFormat:@"&text=%@" goodValue];
        NSData * postData = [post dataUsingEncoding:NSASCIIStringEncoding allowLossyConversion:NO];
        NSString * postLength = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d",[postData length]];
        NSMutableURLRequest * request = [[NSMutableURLRequest alloc] init];
        [request setURL:[NSURL URLWithString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"http://website.de/test.php"]]];
        [request setHTTPMethod:@"POST"];
        [request setValue:postLength forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Length"];
        [request setValue:@"application/x-www-form-urlencoded" forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Type"];
        [request setHTTPBody:postData];
        NSURLConnection * conn = [[NSURLConnection alloc] initWithRequest:request delegate:self];
```

in php:

```
$text = $_POST['text'];

$result = dbquery("INSERT INTO test (text) VALUES ('$text')");
```

it makes me angry -.-, how can i send umlauts from ios to php??

Comment: It's the same as everywhere else: Use UTF-8 explicitly and everywhere. Send headers, set db connections, check correct byte sequences, etc...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You shouldn't use `NSASCIIStringEncoding`. Use `NSUTF8StringEncoding` instead.

```
NSData * postData = [post dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding allowLossyConversion:NO];
```